# Adding <td> name as dynamically using javascript not working while adding id works

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am creating a table and adding  and  as follows:

```
 var table = document.getElementById("resumes_table");
     var rowcount = document.getElementById("resumes_table").rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowcount);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     cell2.id = "a"+rowcount;
     cell2.name = "a"+rowcount;
     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4)
```

I am adding id and name to my  (cell) as follows:

```
cell2.id = "a"+rowcount;
cell2.name = "a"+rowcount;
```

Where id is working while `cell2.name = "a"+rowcount;` **not working.**

Comment: how does "not working" not work?

Comment: @AmitJoki after adding that I inspected it. but name not showing!!

Comment: Have you tried to use `cell2.setAttribute("name", "a" + rowcount)`? See http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: What happens if you try `cell2.setAttribute('name', 'a' + rowcount)`?

Comment: The second line can be shortened like this: `var rowcount = table.rows.length`. You already have the first part of the expression in the variable `table`. Also please outdent all lines beginning from the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table cells (`<td>`) do not have a `name` property.
You can check the full list of properties for the table cell element [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp)

You can check that by doing:

```
console.log(cell2.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

Or:

```
console.log(cell2.name);
```

Even though you are able to do `cell2.name = "a"+rowcount;` and probably if you check the `cell2` variable after setting the name you will see the property set, when the browser renders the element, it won't take the `name` property into account because it's not part of the element's specs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the "name" properties of a `<td>` element because `<td>` don't have that kind of properties. Just check on w3cschools website.

Just a hint. Actually can't add a comment so I have to insert an answer. When you insert a question, you have to `use "Code Sample"` to insert code as `<td>` or when the question is published `<td>` will become invisible.